# Excel cell address in formulas

Tags: excel, variables

I'm attempting to alter a cell address in a line of formulas that goes on for 36 lines,
the formulas reads like this,

```
='sheet2'!J2

='sheet3'!J2

='sheet4'!J2
```

I'd like to be able to change `J2` to another address without having to manually input it into every formula every time.

Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: Could the `ADDRESS (row_num, col_num, [abs_num], [a1], [sheet])` function be adapted to what you are looking for?

Comment: @ryyker I now see that you had the same idea before me. But I already worked it out and posted. So let my work not go to waste :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Find and Replace.
Select all cells you want to change and hit CTRL+H.

Example below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! this was exactly what I needed!

Comment: @DavidSimpson You are welcome. You can vote the answer up and select as "answered"

Answer (score 2):

Consider replacing your formula with this one.

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,10,1,1,"Sheet"&ROW()))
```

The point is to have a single formula for all your rows. This is achieved by using the ROW() function which returns the number of the row in which it resides. `"Sheet" & Row()` will therefore result in `Sheet2` in row 2, `Sheet3` in row 3 and so on. If you need the *Sheet2* in row 5 then you use `Row()+3` while `INT(ROW()/2)` will enable you to use alternating rows. You can modify the above formula to match any pattern of repetition you might need.

The above formula points at J2. `ADDRESS(2,10)` specifies row 2 and column 10 (column J = column 10). However, you can replace the hard reference with a soft one. Here is a variation of the above taking the column number from cell G1. To change from column J to M you can just enter 10 or 13 in G1.

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,$G$1,1,1,"Sheet"&ROW()))
```

Note that the $ signs in `$G$1` are necessary because you want to copy the formula. But if you would rather enter a column letter in G1 then the variation below will allow you to do that.

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,CODE(UPPER($G$1))-64,1,1,"Sheet"&ROW()))
```

As you see, every parameter of the ADDRESS() function can be entered directly or using a reference which makes this formula very versatile. And, of course, it's first and foremost advantage is that you don't need a different one in each row of your report. So, it saves maintenance time, too.